# Terraform "google_api_gateway_api_config": params "openapi_documents.document.path" vs. "content"

Tags: terraform, google-api-gateway

I'm reading the sample code for the Terraform resource [google_api_gateway_api_config](https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/google/latest/docs/resources/api_gateway_api_config#example-usage---apigateway-api-config-basic):

```
resource "google_api_gateway_api_config" "api_cfg" {
  ...
  openapi_documents {
    document {
      path = "spec.yaml"
      contents = filebase64("test-fixtures/apigateway/openapi.yaml")
```

**Question:** Why are both `path` and `contents` needed (wouldn't `path` imply `contents`)? Why does the sample code use 2 different folders/filenames -- shouldn't they use the same folder/filename?

In comparison, the CLI [gcloud api-gateway api-configs create](https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/reference/api-gateway/api-configs/create) has just 1 (as opposed to 2) param: `--openapi-spec` which is the local folder/filename such as `/tmp/openapi_spec.yaml` (and therefore implies the file content).

Comment: According to the documentation `path` is the uploaded path and not the source.

Comment: That explanation (from docs) doesn't explain it. (1) I don't see an "uploaded path" in either GCP Console or the output of `gcloud api-gateway api-configs describe ...`. (2) `gcloud api-gateway api-configs create` doesn't need us to specify such a mysterious "uploaded path". What "uploaded path" is it talking about?

Comment: Let me amend my comments above. I now see the so-called `path` attribute displayed in the output of `gcloud api-gateway api-configs describe ... --view=FULL`. That attrib is explained in GCP docs here: https://cloud.google.com/api-gateway/docs/reference/rest/v1beta/projects.locations.apis.configs#file But it still doesn't explain point (2) of my comment above, i.e., `gcloud api-gateway api-configs create` doesn't need it. Overall, this attrib is just useless, right?